# Evaluate: $\lim_{n \to \infty}[(1+\frac{1}{n})^n-(1+\frac{1}{n})]^{-n}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, logarithms

> Evaluate: $$\lim_{n \to \infty}[(1+\frac{1}{n})^n-(1+\frac{1}{n})]^{-n}$$

attemp: Take $P=\lim_{n \to \infty}[(1+\frac{1}{n})^n-(1+\frac{1}{n})]^{-n}$ . Then taking **log** both side .$$\ln P=-\lim_{n \to \infty}n\ln [(1+\frac{1}{n})^n-(1+\frac{1}{n})]$$.Then stuck. Please help.

Comment: Do you know what $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$ is?

Comment: yes.It is equal to **e**.

Answer (score 5):

$(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$ tends to $e$ as $n$ increases, so for big enough $n$ it's between $2$ and $3$. Then you can continue with squeeze theorem for example. We have $$\frac{3}{2} \le 2 - (1+\frac{1}{n})\le(1+\frac{1}{n})^n-(1+\frac{1}{n}) \le 3 -(1+\frac{1}{n})\le 2$$ for big $n$. We see that $\lim_{n \to \infty}(\frac{3}{2})^{-n} = \lim_{n \to \infty}(2)^{-n} = 0$, so $\lim_{n \to \infty}[(1+\frac{1}{n})^n-(1+\frac{1}{n})]^{-n}$ is also $0$

Comment: Please explain it more.

Answer (score 4):

What you have done is wrong because you assumed the limit existed.

We must evaluate
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}[(1+\frac{1}{n})^n-(1+\frac{1}{n})]^{-n}=
\lim_{n \to \infty}e^{\log[(1+\frac{1}{n})^n-(1+\frac{1}{n})](-n)}
$$
Remember $$\lim_{n \to \infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^n=e$$
Thus, because $e>2$
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\log[(1+\frac{1}{n})^n-(1+\frac{1}{n})](-n)=\log(e-1)(-\infty)=-\infty
$$
By continuity of $e^x$,
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}[(1+\frac{1}{n})^n-(1+\frac{1}{n})]^{-n}=
\lim_{n \to \infty}e^{\log[(1+\frac{1}{n})^n-(1+\frac{1}{n})](-n)}=e^{-\infty}=0
$$

Comment: @Jabali: You wanted Adam to explain more but you have a complete answer here! :-)

Comment: I don't understand adam's word.So I asked to explain.But I don't understand here how I conclude that limit does not exist.

Comment: @DonAntonio Oh my! That's a serious mistake. I will correct this immediately